# Is there a way to tell from which external site the user navigate from?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to tell from which external site the user navigate from?

Answer (score 0):

look at the referrer request header.  Request.UrlReferrer

UPDATE 1:
  if UrlReferrer is null then there was no referrer header, meaning they did not navigate from another site.

Comment: I tried that in debug mode, but it was null / nothing. I was wondering if that was due some debug quirk.

Comment: did you navigate to your debug mode app from an external site? :)

Comment: load a link up into an existing external site that points to your debug app.  Click it and see what happens.

Comment: tHAT'S WHAT i DID DO. uRLrEFERRER WAS nOTHING (null)